# How to select all values of a field that has specific values in another field?

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which the field 'id_px' can have some repeated values because it has a different value in the field 'id_category' and I want to retrieve all values on 'id_px' that has the exact values that I pass.  For example:

```
SELECT id_px FROM my_table WHERE id_category = 1 **AND** id_category = 32;
```

I found a way that retrieves me the result that I want:

```
SELECT id_px
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id_px
HAVING SUM(id_category NOT IN (1,32)) = 0
AND SUM(id_category = 1) = 1
AND SUM(id_category = 32) = 1
```

but I want to use it whitout the HAVING clause because I have to use some UNION clause.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use OR in the first query? As I understood you only want records having specific values of id_category.

Comment: Not because I need you to have both specifically. Not if you have one. I need you to have both ids specifically.

Comment: could you update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result?

Comment: You can use `group by` or try `join` table with it-self to find `id_px`s that has both of `id_category`  @MarvinCalderon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest some ways:

3- 3rd one: (Worked and marked as an Answer)

```
SELECT tbl.id_px FROM
  (SELECT id_px ,
    SUM(id_category NOT IN (1,32)) as b ,
    SUM(id_category = 1) as t1 , SUM(id_category = 32) as t2
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY id_px) as tbl
WHERE tbl.b = 0 AND tbl.t1 = 1 AND tbl.t2 = 1
```

4- Re-Building Query-2 :

4.1-first steps of rebuilding: (*inefficient*)

```
SELECT tbl.id_px FROM
  (SELECT id_px , CONCAT('-,' , GROUP_CONCAT(id_category),',') as gr
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY id_px
  ) as tbl
  WHERE
      INSTR( tbl.gr , ',1,'  )>0
  AND INSTR( tbl.gr , ',32,' )>0
  AND LENGTH(tbl.gr)-LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(tbl.gr,',1,' ,''), ',32,' ,'')) = LENGTH(CONCAT(',1,' , ',32,' ))
```

last condition in `WHERE` is replacing 1 and 32 from `tbl.gr` and comparing reduced `LENGTH` if reduced length is equal to 1 and 32 string, there were just 1 and 32 so rewrite query to this one:

4.2- New possibly working query: (*simplified*)

```
SELECT tbl.id_px FROM
  (SELECT id_px , GROUP_CONCAT(id_category) as gr
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY id_px
  ) as tbl
  WHERE
      tbl.gr = '1,32' or tbl.gr = '32,1'
```

---

Without any sample data it seems these are ok, but they didn't good answer while problem is limiting id_category to exactly have two values and no other id_category.

**NOTE: These two queries, selects `id_px` that has `id_category` 1,32 and maybe many other id_category, so these are not acceptable answer for this question**

*2- Selecting `id_px` by `join`*

```
SELECT a.id_px
FROM my_table as a
LEFT JOIN my_table as b
ON a.id_px = b.id_px
WHERE a.id_category = 1 AND b.id_category = 32
GROUP BY a.id_px
```

*1- Using `group by` and searching in `id_px`:*

```
SELECT tbl.id_px FROM
  (SELECT id_px , CONCAT('-,' , GROUP_CONCAT(id_category),',') as gr
   FROM my_table
   GROUP BY id_px
  ) as tbl
  WHERE
      INSTR( tbl.gr , ',1,'  )>0
  AND INSTR( tbl.gr , ',32,' )>0
```

Comment: The first one throws 'Invalid use of group function' and the second one doesnt retrieve the desired values.

Comment: The first one and second one update!  @MarvinCalderon

Comment: And 3rd suggest added which is similar to your original query @MarvinCalderon

Comment: Because it's your own query with a bit updates :)) @MarvinCalderon

Comment: Only with an observation ... Why if id_px has one of the categories repeated why it shows? It should be the ones with only 1 AND 32. Not that I have 1 or 32 repeated?

Comment: I was thinking (id_px , id_category) is unique! it seems I'm wrong. so I update the code where new line is: `SUM(id_category = 1) as t1 , SUM(id_category = 32) as t2` and `where` is updated too @MarvinCalderon

Comment: Thank you very much @MohaMad! Thats the correct answer, option 3.

Comment: These are all very innefficient (2 particularly so) method 3 adds additional logic not present in methods 1 and 2

Comment: Without any sample data it seems these are ok, but they didn't good answer while problem is limiting id_category to exactly have two values and no other id_category. @symcbean

Comment: by your comment, trying to use query-2 and building query-4.2 ! @symcbean